# Is the query I wrote for given problem statement correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

What should be the query for this problem statement in MySQL Workbench 8.0?

> Q. How many movies were produced in the USA or India in the year 2019?
>
> Hint: USA and India produced more than a thousand movies in the year 2019.

This is the query I have used (but I have the feeling that this might not be absolutely correct!)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT title) AS no_of_movies
FROM
    movie
WHERE
    year = 2019 AND country='India' OR country='USA';
```

`title` holds movie names so I counted all unique movies.

Do I need to make any changes?

Comment: If you are not getting the expected number of results for a given query, find a row manually that you believe should be included but is not, and then debug why that one row is not being included.

Answer (score 1):

First, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` should not be necessary.  The `DISTINCT` incurs overhead so it should only be used when necessary.  Just count the matching rows.  Second, the `WHERE` clause is not correct.  As written, it need parentheses:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_movies
FROM movie
WHERE year = 2019 AND (country = 'India' OR country = 'USA');
```

The `WHERE` can be simplified using `IN`:

```
WHERE year = 2019 AND country IN ('India', 'USA');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but the result is giving me output as no_of_movies = 887 i.e is less than 1000 as per the hint?

Comment: @JayThakur . . . Perhaps something is wrong with the country names in the data.

Comment: @JayThakur: change the `country` comparison to `...UPPER(country) IN ('INDIA', 'USA')` and see if that makes a difference.